# Copying features from one layer into another in PyQGIS using addFeatures

Tags: pyqgis, layers, copy

I am writing a plugin for QGIS 3.8

I have two layers,

- drop_layer and
- Fibre Cable.

I want to copy all features from the drop_layer and append to Fibre cable layer.

I use a function to create drop_layer using some processing tools. Then I use following function `merge_to_original_Fibre_layer` to copy all features of this "drop_layer" to another existing layer "Fibre cable". All these functions are part of the main class.

```
def merge_to_original_Fibre_layer(self):
    dlayer = self.drop_layer.getFeatures()
    layerObject = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Fibre Cable")[0]
    features = []
    for f in dlayer:
        features.append(f)
    layerObject.startEditing()
    layerObject.addFeatures(features)
    layerObject.commitChanges()
```

When I run the code, all the features of "drop_layer" are getting copied to "Fibre Cable" layer. I see this when I open the attribute table of the layer "Fibre Cable". Even I am able to zoom map to these features.

The problem is I cannot see the geometry of these newly added features on the map. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `layerObject.updateExtents()`.

Comment: Tried your advice. Still the added features are not visible. :(

Comment: Replace the last 3 lines in your function with: `layerObject.dataProvider().addFeatures(features)`

Comment: You will find this section of the pyqgis developer cookbook useful: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#editing

Comment: @Ben W, tried your advice. still added features are not visible. ;(

Comment: You are sure that both layers are in the same crs??

Comment: @Ben W, yes crs of both the layers are same. 
But "Fibre cable" layer has Geometry: Line (MultiLineString)
whereas "drop_layer" which is created from shortestpath processing tool and it has Geometry:  Line (LineString).
May be this geometry difference is causing the problem. Is there any method to convert LineString to MultiLineString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was fine. The issue was with rule-based symbology. Fibre Cable layer had an attribute rule-based symbology.
I added the required attributes to the added features and features were visible.